# PocketSphinx on Android setKeywordThreshold() issue

Tags: pocketsphinx-android

I would like to lower the threshold via setKeywordThreshold() method.
The default value of this in the official demo app is 1e-45.
I was told that the minimal value could be 1e-200.
See this article: https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/05d09693/?limit=25

So, I tried to set it to be 1e-150,  but the Android Studio complained that the threshold value should be in type "float", not "double".

Can anybody tell me how to set it up to lower than 1e-45?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue in older versions, which one are you using? The type of argument was changed from `float` to `double` in `setFloat` method, so you can use `1e-200` there safely.

You can also use kws list file with `setKws` without the need to pass threshold through API.